# custom android arrayadapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Not sure how to describe this one so I'll just do my best. I have a ListView that always displays five strings whatever is selected. I've copied an example to place images at the left of each list item. However I have five separate images and I don't know how to set each respective image in the custom array adapter. The current code is as follows:

> ```
> String s = values[position];
> if (s.startsWith("Windows")) {
>   imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
> } else {
>   imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
> }
> ```

I want mine to do the following:

```
if index = 0 then setImageResource as image1; elseif index = 1 then setImageResource as image2, etc.
```

Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are static values. Why you don't use switch statement. For example:

```
switch(position)
{
  case 0:
  imageView.setImage(R.drawable.image1);
  break;
  .
  .
  .
  .
  case 4:
  imageView.setImage(R.drawable.image5);
  break;
}
```

Comment: Excellent Arben. That's just what it needed.

Answer (score 0):

Another clean solution would be creating a POJO of the your array item.

```
class Item{
    String text;
    int imageId;

  //respective setter getters

 }
```

In your array adapter,the getView method, modify it accordingly